# Sort Array Based on Two Parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array of objects that consist of two properties: an `NSString` and a `BOOL`. I'd like to sort this array so that all the `BOOL`s that are `YES` appear before all the bools that are `NO`. Then I'd like for the list of objects that have the `BOOL YES` to alphabetized and I'd also like for the objects with the `NO` to be alphabetized. Is there some sort of library that can accomplish this in objective c? If not what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `NSSortDescriptor`s to do the sorting:

```
// Set ascending:NO so that "YES" would appear ahead of "NO"
NSSortDescriptor *boolDescr = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"boolField" ascending:NO];
// String are alphabetized in ascending order
NSSortDescriptor *strDescr = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"strField" ascending:YES];
// Combine the two
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[boolDescr, strDescr];
// Sort your array
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

You can read more about sorting with descriptors [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using sort descriptors is to use an `NSComparator`:

```
NSArray *myObjects = ... // your array of "Foo" objects
NSArray *sortedArray = [myObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Foo *obj1, Foo *obj2) {
    if ((obj1.boolProp && obj2.boolProp) || (!obj1.boolProp && !obj2.boolProp)) {
        // Both bools are either YES or both are NO so sort by the string property
        return [obj1.stringProp compare:obj2.stringProp];
    } else if (obj1.boolProp) {
        // first is YES, second is NO
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        // second is YES, first is NO
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
)];
```

Please note that I may have the last two backward. If this sorts the No values before the Yes values then swap the last two return values.

Answer (score 2):

Look up NSSortDescriptors. Create two, one for the string, one for the bool. Then add both to an array. Then use NSArray method sortedArrayWiyhDescriptors.